# How to exclude or not print previous found entries in script

Tags: perl

Can someone shed some light on how to have my script kick off only if new entries are found for the current hour? Our logs are based in 00 01 02, etc.

When this runs it will look for any accounts specified within my `for` loop and send an email if this particular user made a cert change for the hour. If a match is found then everything is fine.

But I am interested only in new real-time entries which I can't figure out.

This will be run from a cron, and I can't have it repeating the same entry.  I am new to Perl and can't seem to figure this out.

I have tried the [`File::Tail`](https://p3rl.org/File::Tail) module and other CPAN mods but due to company policies some mods are not allowed.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $flag = 0;
my $few = shift || 1;
my $id;
my $newline;
my $partyId;
my $userid;
my $tid;
my $infile;
my @Takeraccounts = ( 'SCN', 'CX' );
my $mail_dest = 'xxxxx@cx.com';

my %TIME;

(
    $TIME{SEC},  $TIME{MIN},  $TIME{HOUR}, $TIME{MDAY}, $TIME{MON},
    $TIME{YEAR}, $TIME{WDAY}, $TIME{YDAY}, $TIME{ISDST}
) = localtime(time);

my $OLD_MIN  = $TIME{MIN};
my $OLD_HOUR = $TIME{HOUR};

my $cmd      = "cat /raid/logs/`date +%H`";
my $out_file = "/home/resource/certchange.txt";

open FF, "$cmd |";
open( OUT, ">> $out_file" ) || die "Cannot open $out_file";    # temp file to which to write the formated output

while ( <FF> ) {

    my $line = $_;

    #chomp ($now_time);
    $line =~ s/\n/ /;
    if ( /Updating cert/ .. /,permissions/ ) {

        $newline = "$line";

        if ( $line =~ /Updating cert.*updated by (\w+)/ ) {
            $id = $1;
        }

        if ( $newline =~ /UPDATE.*id:(\w+).*partyId:(\w+),perm:/ ) {

            $userid  = $1;
            $partyId = $2;

            foreach (@Takeraccounts) {

                if ( $partyId =~ /$_/ ) {
                    print OUT "Certificate cert Updated by $id for userid $userid, PartyID $partyId\n";
                    open ML, "| mutt -e\"set realname='Support'; set use_from=yes; set from='support\@cx.com'; set envelope_from=yes\" -s ' Alert! cert CHANGED' -i $out_file -- $mail_dest";
                    close ML;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

close FF;
close(OUT);

unlink $out_file;
```

Comment: Every time you sucessfully sent a letter, save user name you've already processed to hash and serialize it to some file/DB. On next run read it and ignore users already in this hash.

Comment: May you clarify: You parse log and check if user made change. If so you send mail. May you clarify what is problem and what you mean: 'But I am interested only in new real-time entries'

Comment: So if a particular user makes a change, the id, userid and partyid would get written to a file and then contents sent to an email alert. Since the script is run on a cron every minute, if the log file does not change on next run a duplicate email alert will be sent out for the previous user id making those changes.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid this happening by if the log does not change and if it's the same user id who made the change to do nothing. I've been reading about using a hash but I'm still very new to perl and struggling for a solution.

Comment: open($cmd, "tail -n 23 /raid/logs/date +%H |");